# Which MacBook supports Thunderbolt 3 and has regular USB 3 ports?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, thunderbolt

I'm looking to upgrade my MacBook Air to something with the new Thunderbolt 3 ports, but also has USB 3 ports. There seem to be so many models out there, but I didn't find one.

Which MacBooks have Thunderbolt 3 and USB 3 ports without the need of an extra adapter?

Answer (score 3):

> Which MacBook supports Thunderbolt 3 and has regular USB 3 ports??

**None.**

Currently, the only "MacBook" that supports Thunderbolt 3 are the MacBook Pros that were released in 2016 and on.  Those only have USB-C type Thunderbolt ports.  If you are looking for something that will give you USB-A ports along with USB 3.0 compatibility, you will need a (dreaded) [dongle](http://radnex.us/usbc-multi-port-adapter-power-delivery-hdmi).

The [2016 MacBook Pro 15"](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP749?locale=en_US) (with and without Touchbar) has the following ports:

> **Charging and Expansion** Four Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) ports with support for:
>
> - Charging
> - DisplayPort
> - Thunderbolt (up to 40 Gbps)
> - USB 3.1 Gen 2 (up to 10 Gbps)

The [13" model](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP747?locale=en_US) has only 2 Thunderbolt ports:

> **Charging and Expansion** Two Thunderbolt 3  (USB-C) ports with support for:
>
> - Charging
> - DisplayPort
> - Thunderbolt (up to 40 Gbps)
> - USB 3.1 Gen 2 (up to 10 Gbps)

The [MacBook Air](https://www.apple.com/macbook-air/specs/) (2015) only supports Thunderbolt 2 while the latest [MacBook](https://www.apple.com/macbook/specs/) only support USB-C with DisplayPort (no Thunderbolt).

Comment: mac is really pushing my limits.

Comment: And the worst part is Microsoft includes USB-A but no USB-C or Thunderbolt.  Don't get me started on Dell.  Their website alone sends me off a cliff.

Comment: @Allan Don't forget to bring a parachute!

Comment: thinkpad it is.